# How do I dynamically toggle multiple layers in Deck.gl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, data-visualization, deck.gl

[image]
I am building a basic visualization system that layers can be toggled from the control box.
I have `layers` that merge individual layers into one.

`const [layers, setLayers] = useState([densityLayer, pedestrianLayer]);`

I have `filterState` that tracks the activity in the control box. It contains the layer object as a property of `linkTo`

```
 const [filterState, setFilterState] = useState([
        {
          id: 'densityFilter',
          checked: true,
          description: 'Population density',
          linkedTo: densityLayer
        },
        {
          id: 'pedestrianFilter',      
          checked: true,
          description: 'Pedestrian volume',
          linkedTo: pedestrianLayer
        }
      ]);
```

and everytime checked property in `filterState` gets updated, it launches `renderLayers()`
which will select corresponding layers whose `checked` property is `true`.

```
  useEffect(()=>{
        renderLayers();
      },[filterState]);

      const renderLayers = () => {
        const newLayers = []; 
        filterState.map(filter => (filter.checked && newLayers.push(filter.linkedTo)));
        setLayers(newLayers);
      }
```

Then `layers` is passed to `DeckGL` component as a layer prop.

```
   <DeckGL
        initialViewState={viewState}
        controller={true}
        layers={layers}
      >
```

In my program, turning off the layers works fine, but they do not turn back on. In the console, I noticed that the lifecycles between layers are different. Is there anything incorrect about my approach?

Comment: Can you post the code that creates `densityLayer` and `pedestrianLayer`?

Answer (score 6):

Have you try to use visible property of layers? If you are going to switch multiple time and often, deck.gl suggests to use visible instead of recreated a new layer.
Some useful resources about this thread:

- [Creating layer instances is cheap](https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/using-layers#creating-layer-instances-is-cheap).
- [Layer visibility over addition and removal](https://deck.gl/docs/developer-guide/performance#favor-layer-visibility-over-addition-and-removal).
- [Visible property](https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/core/layer#visible).

First, create a Control box, like you did.
Then pass as props to DeckGL component what you selected from control box.

```
{
    layer1: true, layer2: false, layer3: false, layer4: false,
}
```

Create a state for layers.

```
const [activeLayers, setActiveLayers] = useState(layersProps);
```

Check with useEffect when something changes in layersProps.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const layers = {
        layer1: false,
        layer2: false,
        layer3: false,
        layer4: false,
    };

    if (typeMap === 'layer1') {
        layers.layer1 = true;
    } else if (typeMap === 'layer2') {
        layers.layer2 = true;
    }
    ...

    setActiveLayers(layers);
}, [layerProps]);
```

Or you can create a state

```
const [activeLayers, setActiveLayers] = useState({
    layer1: true, layer2: false,
});
```

And pass as props only what you selected from control box and check for changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const layers = {
        layer1: false,
        layer2: false,
    };

    if (typeMap === 'layer1') {
        layers.layer1 = true;
    } else if (typeMap === 'layer2') {
        layers.layer2 = true;
    }
    ...

    setActiveLayers(layers);
}, [inputLayerSelected]);
```

If you prefer you can also split each layer with a single one state (so you have a primitive value).

Finaly, you can create your layer

```
const layer1 = new ScatterplotLayer({
    id: 'scatter',
    data: data,
    ....
    visible: activeLayers.layer1, OR
    visible: layer1
});
```

and render

```
<DeckGL
    layers={[layer1, layer2, layer3, layer4]}
    ...
>
```

Comment: The links are broken. Could you please update? Thanks!

Comment: @FlorinVîrdol fixed

Comment: Can I request a full code? I don't know how to create a control box. Kindly help